# Python: how to split pandas DataFrame into subsets based on the value in the first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big logfile (.txt) of my experiment (containing up to 100 000 entries) that has the following structure:

```
ROUTINE    TEMPERATURE    VOLTAGE    WAVELENGTH
_______________________________________________
CHANGE T   75             0          560
CHANGE T   80             0          560
CHANGE T   85             0          560
CHANGE T   90             0          560
OSL        75             20         570
OSL        75             20         580
OSL        75             20         590
OSL        75             20         600
CHANGE T   75             0          560
CHANGE T   80             0          560
CHANGE T   85             0          560
CHANGE T   90             0          560
```

I load the logfile into python using *read_table* from *pandas*. I would like to devide the resulting dataframe into smaller dataframes based on the value of the first column. So the result would look like this:

```
**DATAFRAME 1:**    
CHANGE T   75             0          560
CHANGE T   80             0          560
CHANGE T   85             0          560
CHANGE T   90             0          560

**DATAFRAME 2:** 
OSL        75             20         570
OSL        75             20         580
OSL        75             20         590
OSL        75             20         600

**DATAFRAME 3:** 
CHANGE T   75             0          560
CHANGE T   80             0          560
CHANGE T   85             0          560
CHANGE T   90             0          560
```

First I tried to split them using the indices where the value of first column changes:

```
indexSplit = [] # list containing the boundry indices

prevRoutine = log['ROUTINE'][0] # log is the complete dataframe
i = 1
while i < len(log):
        if prevRoutine != log['ROUTINE'][i]:
            indexSplit.append(i)
        prevRoutine = log['ROUTINE'][i]
```

However taking into account the size of the logfile it takes a huge amount of time to do it this way (obviously). I was wondering if there is an elegant way to do this with pandas? The problem I keep running into is that the values of the first column  are used in more than one series. I always end up with *dataframe 1* and *dataframe 3* as one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` where loop `groupby` object and `groups` are created by `s`. There compare by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (same as `!=` but faster) [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed column and by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) get output:

```
s = df['ROUTINE'].ne(df['ROUTINE'].shift()).cumsum()
print (s)
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    3
Name: ROUTINE, dtype: int32

dfs = [g for i,g in df.groupby(df['ROUTINE'].ne(df['ROUTINE'].shift()).cumsum())]
print (dfs)
[    ROUTINE  TEMPERATURE  VOLTAGE  WAVELENGTH
0  CHANGE T           75        0         560
1  CHANGE T           80        0         560
2  CHANGE T           85        0         560
3  CHANGE T           90        0         560,   ROUTINE  TEMPERATURE  VOLTAGE  WAVELENGTH
4     OSL           75       20         570
5     OSL           75       20         580
6     OSL           75       20         590
7     OSL           75       20         600,      ROUTINE  TEMPERATURE  VOLTAGE  WAVELENGTH
8   CHANGE T           75        0         560
9   CHANGE T           80        0         560
10  CHANGE T           85        0         560
11  CHANGE T           90        0         560]
```

---

```
print (dfs[0])
    ROUTINE  TEMPERATURE  VOLTAGE  WAVELENGTH
0  CHANGE T           75        0         560
1  CHANGE T           80        0         560
2  CHANGE T           85        0         560
3  CHANGE T           90        0         560

print (dfs[1])
  ROUTINE  TEMPERATURE  VOLTAGE  WAVELENGTH
4     OSL           75       20         570
5     OSL           75       20         580
6     OSL           75       20         590
7     OSL           75       20         600

print (dfs[2])
     ROUTINE  TEMPERATURE  VOLTAGE  WAVELENGTH
8   CHANGE T           75        0         560
9   CHANGE T           80        0         560
10  CHANGE T           85        0         560
11  CHANGE T           90        0         560
```

---

Solution is complicated, because if use `groupby` for first column only get only 2 groups:

```
dfs = [g for i,g in df.groupby('ROUTINE')]
print (dfs)
[     ROUTINE  TEMPERATURE  VOLTAGE  WAVELENGTH
0   CHANGE T           75        0         560
1   CHANGE T           80        0         560
2   CHANGE T           85        0         560
3   CHANGE T           90        0         560
8   CHANGE T           75        0         560
9   CHANGE T           80        0         560
10  CHANGE T           85        0         560
11  CHANGE T           90        0         560,   ROUTINE  TEMPERATURE  VOLTAGE  WAVELENGTH
4     OSL           75       20         570
5     OSL           75       20         580
6     OSL           75       20         590
7     OSL           75       20         600]
```

Comment: What does `pandas.DataFrame.ne`perform ?

Comment: sorry, give me a time.

Comment: `In [470]: %timeit (df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum())
1 loop, best of 3: 481 ms per loop

In [471]: %timeit ((df['a'] != df['a'].shift()).cumsum())
1 loop, best of 3: 1.56 s per loop

In [472]: %timeit (df['b'].ne(df['b'].shift()).cumsum())
1 loop, best of 3: 209 ms per loop

In [473]: %timeit ((df['b'] != df['b'].shift()).cumsum())
1 loop, best of 3: 210 ms per loop` for `10M`

Comment: Thank you very much, it was exactly what I needed and it runs in no time!